# UnexpectedJavaScriptError when opening IE using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll 
but was not handled in user code
Additional information: JavaScript error (UnexpectedJavaScriptError)
```

I'm trying to browse a url using IE.
I get this error only for Internet explorer. For chrome & firefox it works fine.

Using IE 11, IEDriverServer_Win32_2.47.0, Windows 7 64-bit

**C#:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void GeneratePageSnaps()
{
 IWebDriver NewDriver;
 NewDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver("D:\IeDriver");
 NewDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
 NewDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
 IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(NewDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.00));
 wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)NewDriver).ExecuteScript(
                        "return document.readyState").Equals("complete")); //error here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must read the document before using it :

The InternetExplorerDriver is a standalone server which implements WebDriver's wire protocol. **This driver has been tested with IE 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 on appropriate combinations of XP, Vista and Windows 7.**

The driver supports running 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the browser. The choice of how to determine which "bit-ness" to use in launching the browser depends on which version of the IEDriverServer.exe is launched. If the **32-bit version of IEDriverServer.exe is launched, the 32-bit version of IE will be launched**. Similarly, **if the 64-bit version of IEDriverServer.exe is launched, the 64-bit version of IE will be launched.**

[Read More ...](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

And this one is for you :

**For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.**

**For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.**

Comment: I created the key in registry. Still the same error

Comment: Then its must be due to IE version, try using the older version, also try to use same bit for both

Comment: you mean older version of ie? I did not understand "same bit for both"

Comment: same bit means the IDESERVER bit and your windows OS and IE bit version like 32 or 64 bit and yaa older version of IE like Internet Explorer 10 or 9

Comment: Tried with both 32 & 64 bit versions of the driver.No luck. I dont have a lower version and I have to check for IE 11 as part of the task

Comment: use lower IE version .. it works fine .. i checked it yesterday for IE 9

Comment: @Qwerty I also have similar problem tried this solution but didn't work, does this work lowering the version of IE?

Answer (score -1):

Try resetting your IE browser settings.
It worked for me, just go to the

> ***settings>Internet Options>Advanced>Reset***

Just reset and restart the system.
NOTE:

For Selenium web driver to work with IE the following should also need to be done :
 Internet Options>Security, Select "Enable protected mode" for all the 4 options then Apply these changes and then restart the systems..then only it works.